# diff'ing without grouping unrelated blocks

Tags: algorithm, diff

Is there a diff algorithm that does not group unrelated blocks?

For example:

```
hello world
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

vs.

```
Hello World
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
```

Comparing these (e.g. with standard Unix `diff`) generally results in the following:

```
< hello world
< lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
---
> Hello World
> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
```

However, a line-by-line comparison like the following would seem more sensible:

```
< hello world
---
> Hello World

< lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
---
> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
```

The latter, IMO, makes it much easier to analyze minor changes. (Note that I'm concerned with human readability here, not machine readability.)

I understand diff'ing is a complex issue, but this often leaves me puzzled nonetheless.

Comment: How should the diff algorithm know if the two lines are related?

Comment: Well, if it's just a tiny amount of changes (e.g. capitalization or indentation), it should be able to recognize that - indeed, inline diff'ing already does this to some extent (see comments below).

Answer (score 4):

Although it is [intentional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) that [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) behaves like that you can change it by throwing in blank lines. This will get the result you want.

1:

```
hello world

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Same
```

2:

```
Hello World

Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet

Same
```

The line number has to be fixed though (n/2 + 1).

```
1c1
< hello world
---
> Hello World
3c3
< lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
---
> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
```

If multiple lines replace one line the output may still not be what you want:

```
1,3c1
< hello world
<
< lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
---
> Hello World
```

Comment: Thanks - I have used this workaround before, but it's not a viable generic solution (see my response to mizipzor).
I suppose the LCS problem explains why it is like it is, so I'll just have to live with it...

Comment: Dont live with it, every software breakthrough starts with an annoyed programmer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal, but better than the other options, you can do (perhaps in a script)

`diff -wu <(sed '/$/G' first.txt) <(sed '/$/G' second.txt) | grep -v '^ *$'`

The main downside is that the line numbers are messed up.

The second downside is that it does not show the filenames (but you can create temporary files rather than using redirection, so that's an easy workaround).

The third downside is that it filters existing lines containing only one space (in addition to the ones artificially introduced, which ought to be filtered).

I actually think this could be a good start for the "writing your own" that everyone is talking about. Second and third downsides can be fixed relatively easily. First one can too, but it's lots of work and not worth at all for what I need this for

Answer (score 1):

The diff algorithm is a solution to the [longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). However, it seems youre not interested in another algorithm. Because, **related or not, both lines have changed** and what you are talking about is how the difference is presented in text.

[Thomas Jung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138749/diffing-without-grouping-unrelated-blocks/2139160#2139160) showed the [original format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Usage). Wikipedia shows a few [variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Variations). But take the time to experiment some.

```
diff original new
```

Will produce the original format.

```
diff -c original new
```

Will produce the [context format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Context_format).

```
diff -u original new
```

Will produce the [unified format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format). For some trivia, this is the one most commonly used, patches to open source projects are more often than not requested in this format.

Of course, if the way the difference is presented to you is crucial, I think you will find any of the [diff viewers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Free_file_comparison_tools) vastly superior.

Comment: Thanks - I know about the different formats (I generally work with `git diff`), but they all present the same issue. This applies to both code and non-code (e.g. wikis) scenarios; minor changes - like indentation or typo corrections - can appear dramatic because it's not clear that each individual line just differs slightly from what it was before.

Comment: Did you check the graphical viewers? Some of them does not only highlight the changed line but the changed characters in that line. I like that sometimes when the lines are a little to long, might help you as well. Also note that in most graphical viewers the lines are not "grouped together" in any way. They dont need to be since the change notification is usually a change in the lines background color.

Comment: I have checked various different options - but take GitHub's diff visualization, for example; while that highlights inline changes, it only works if such changes are not on subsequent lines (i.e. blocks take precedence).

Comment: have you considered writing your own? strictly line by line should be very simple to implement... could be something as simple as piping git diff output to a script you wrote!

Comment: I've considered this - but that would mean it's limited to my local setup, and I've come to realize the issues I've mentioned are mainly of concern in a collaborative context (e.g. GitHub)...